# How to set up stats for HAProxy?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I can't figure out how to set up stats for HAProxy.

This is my configuration:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    daemon
    #debug
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    maxconn 4096

    stats socket /tmp/haproxy

defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option dontlognull
    option redispatch
    option clitcpka
    option srvtcpka
    option tcpka
    retries 3
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout 10000
    clitimeout 50000
    srvtimeout 50000

    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats scope .
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats auth xxxxx:xxxxx

    option contstats

listen rtmp :1935
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin

    server s1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935 check
    server s2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935 check
```

As far as I understand the manual there should be a stats page available via http://mysite/haproxy?stats. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I can access the stats with socat but **not** with a web browser.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

That is not correct. There would be a stats page on http://yoursite.com:1935/haproxy?stats

To overcome this add another listener-

```
listen stats
    bind :1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth Username:Password
```

Then go to http://yoursite.com:1936/ and login.

Make sure your firewall isn't blocking this request on port 1936 (you can change this to whatever you like)

###### As per user suggestions, for newer versions of HAProxy I've moved the bind into the `listen stats` block

Comment: exactly what I needed. kudos! :)

Comment: currently the port `listen stats :1936` not working and you should use a seprare bind `bind :1936` line to specify the port

Answer (score 7):

This did it for me:

```
listen stats
    bind :9000
```

or

```
listen stats
    bind 10.100.86.150:9000
```

Answer (score 6):

In new versions of haproxy (>1.6) you have to set the mode to `http` instead of `tcp` (default) to `config : 'stats' statement ignored for frontend 'http-in' as it requires HTTP mode.`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add script like `bind *:port` for example bind*:80 or you can replace the star symbol with your ip public or ip from machine are installed.

suggestion from me, you can move stats script to one frontend or add one frontend to access stats privately.